# Every Controller that I create now gives the resource cannot be found on views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Hi this is Controller and even when I add View I keep The resource cannot be found. I even tried adding other new Controllers and I keep getting the same error.

```
    [Route("admin")]
    [RoutePrefix("user")]
    public class UserController :Controller
    {

        private readonly IUserRepository _usersRepository;
        private readonly IRoleRepository _rolesRepository;
        private readonly UserService _users;

        public UserController()
        {
            _rolesRepository = new RoleRepository();
            _usersRepository = new UserRepository();
            _users = new UserService(ModelState,_usersRepository,_rolesRepository);
        }
        // GET: Admin/User
        [Route("")]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            using(var manager = new StarPeaceUserManager())
            {
                var users = manager.Users.ToList();
                return View(users);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: why is route set to a empty string?

Comment: Please explain what _"when I add View I keep The resource cannot be found"_ means. We can't see your screen. Who says what at which point? Does Visual Studio show that error when you click Add -> New View? Or can you successfully add a view, but does IIS Express show a 404 error at runtime? Which URL do you visit then?

Comment: I create Controllers and as you can add view I did that, I keep getting the 404 even when I create a new Controller without any code I still the same error when I browse the view.

Comment: You shouldn't browse the view, you need to access an ActionMethod of a controller.

Comment: What is the URL your navigating too, that you expect to hit that Controller Action Method

Comment: I think this is why i find it wise to stay away from Attribute Routing, when a beginner, as you need to understand how the routing in MVC works before you go ahead and start applying route attributes like this.

Comment: @lloyd: There's a route prefix applied to the controller. The empty route says serve this action up at just the URL indicated by the route prefix.